# What's the sort order in mysql if the table have the same data?

Tags: mysql, sql

For example, I have a table named t_student and it has id,name,point three field.If I select the data like this:

```
select * from t_student  order by point desc
```

and the sameple data is:

```
id   name    point

1    name1   99 

2    name2   99 

3    name3   90
```

If the data have the same point, which data should return first: name1 or name2?
What rule is made according to mysql?
If I do some DELETE/INSERT/UPDATE operation and the max point is still 99,does the sql alway return the same result using the following sql?

```
select * from t_student  order by point desc limit 0,1
```

Comment: See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6051/what-is-the-default-order-of-records-for-a-select-statement-in-mysql for a thorough discussion and links to other questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of a tie between two or more records having the same `point` value, the typical way to resolve this would be to add another criteria to the sorting condition, e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM t_student ORDER BY point DESC, name;
```

In the above query, we are trying to break the tie by looking at the `name` field.  We might also use the `id`, or a combination of name and id.

If you want to return all records having the highest `point` value, then you can use a subquery for that:

```
SELECT *
FROM t_student
WHERE point = (SELECT MAX(point) FROM t_student)
ORDER BY name;
```

Comment: If I forget to add another sort filed called name,does the select sql alway return the same result?

Comment: No...if you sort only by `point` then there is no guarantee as to the ordering if two or more records should be tied for points.